# .index() only for one instance of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a problem with `.index()` function in jQuery.

Outline of DOM:

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="threeB"></div>
    <div class="threeB"></div>
    <div class="threeB"></div>
</div>

<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="threeB"></div>
    <div class="threeB"></div>
</div>

<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="threeB"></div>
    <div class="threeB"></div>
    <div class="threeB"></div>
</div>
```

According to which of `three`s in `two` a user clicks, one of the `threeB`s are displayed. I wanted to do this with `.index()` function, but it fails for all but the first ones. In the second `one` class, the two `three`s have indexes 3 and 4 (instead of desired 0 and 1). On the other hand, `.eq()` for `threeB`s seems to work as desired.

Any neat way to solve this without having to count how many `three`s were there before the `div` in question?

Comment: Why don't you show us the selector you are using and tell us what you are actually *trying* to select?

Comment: where is your jquery code you tagged that but no jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working like this:

```
$('.three').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.threeB').eq($(this).index())
        .css('background','green');
});
```

Check here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/SDJTA/)